# Get specific word from a sentence if it has a certain character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to get one single word out of a string if it contains a certain character.

I want to do something like this:

```
string = 'My email is email@example.com and I use it a lot.'

if '@' in string:
    return email
```

But how can I get python to know exactly where the keyword is and return it's value.

In this case it would return `email@example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use regex for your purposes. In this regex pattern `\S*` means "Any non-whitespace character". You can test the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/gPBmB1/1).

```
import re

string = 'My email is email@example.com and I use it a lot.'

search_word = re.search(r'(\S*)@(\S*)', string)
if search_word:
    print(search_word.group())
else:
    print("Word was not found.")
```

Comment: `re.search(r'(\S*@\S*)', string)` should work as well

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension:

```
emails = [i for i in string.split() if '@' in i]
```

Output:

```
['email@example.com']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression to extract your pattern of interest, for example:

```
import re
email = re.search('\w+@\w+([.]\w+)+', string).group(0)
```

Comment: `AttributeError` is raised if no match is found because you'll be trying to access `group(0)` from `None`. Better to assign to `match` and then check if it is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

```
match=re.search(r'([^\s]*@[^\s]*)',string)
if match and match.group(0): print(match.group(0))
```